Example 4.1.1 of Fulton
Let $C$ be a cone over a scheme $X$. Then in Example 4.1.1 from Fulton's Intersection Theory it is stated without proof the equality of Segre classes $s(C\oplus 1)=s(C)$. I was trying to prove this equality, and I imagine it should follow just as in the following discussion of Example 4.1.2 from the same book: Understanding Example 4.1.2 in Fulton's Intersection Theory
(here I'm using that for every irreducible component $C_i$ of $C$, $P(C_i\oplus 1)$ is non-empty).
However, if I want to copy the solution from Example 4.1.2 I should suppose that $C\oplus 1$ is purely $n$-dimension, and the reason for that is explained in the discussion that I linked below: we need this hypothesis to get the equality $c_1(\mathcal{O}(1))\cap [P(C\oplus 1\oplus 1)]=[P(C\oplus 1)]$ (*).
Is it possible to prove that $s(C)=s(C\oplus 1)$ without using ()? Or is () true in this case for another reason? (without using Lemma 1.7.2)
